# GSAP to Velocity Conversion

Tags: javascript, svg, velocity, gsap

I have been working on some Velocity JS animations and trying to learn easing on the go. My JavaScript is fairly rudimentary so I have hit a bit of a stumbling block. This was supposed to be a learning exercise and on the surface it seems fairly trivial but I can't quite grasp what to do.

A designer has passed over a working animation prototype using Edge animate. I'm trying to convert this from images and GSAP code to SVG and Velocity JS. The project already uses Velocity JS for other stuff so it doesn't make sense to include a different library just because that is what Edge uses for one animation.

The animation is a beaker that fades in and then two bubbles use custom easing to bubble out of the top of the beaker.

The SVG for the beaker is on a fiddle and the code GSAP produced is below : http://jsfiddle.net/darker_heroe/9zjrq0zq/

```
<pre>

    "Bubbles": {
        version: "6.0.0",
        minimumCompatibleVersion: "5.0.0",
        build: "6.0.0.400",
        scaleToFit: "none",
        centerStage: "none",
        resizeInstances: false,
        content: {
            dom: [
                {
                    transform: [[], [], [], ['0.5', '0.5']],
                    borderRadius: ['50%', '50%', '50%', '50%'],
                    id: 'Bubble_01',
                    opacity: '0',
                    rect: ['-3px', '-2px', '36px', '36px', 'auto', 'auto'],
                    stroke: [2, 'rgba(234, 239, 240, 0)', 'solid'],
                    type: 'ellipse',
                    autoOrient: 'true',
                    fill: ['rgba(255,255,255,1.00)']
                },
                {
                    transform: [[], [], [], ['0.75', '0.75']],
                    borderRadius: ['50%', '50%', '50%', '50%'],
                    id: 'Bubble_02',
                    opacity: '0',
                    rect: ['3px', '-2px', '29px', '29px', 'auto', 'auto'],
                    stroke: [2, 'rgba(234, 239, 240, 0)', 'solid'],
                    type: 'ellipse',
                    autoOrient: 'true',
                    fill: ['rgba(255,255,255,1)']
                }
            ],
            style: {
                '${symbolSelector}': {
                    rect: [null, null, '40px', '40px']
                }
            }
        },
        timeline: {
            duration: 4000,
            autoPlay: true,
            data: [
                [
                    "eid2211",
                    "opacity",
                    581,
                    919,
                    "easeOutQuad",
                    "${Bubble_02}",
                    '0',
                    '0.5'
                ],
                [
                    "eid2210",
                    "opacity",
                    1500,
                    1000,
                    "easeOutQuad",
                    "${Bubble_02}",
                    '0.5',
                    '0'
                ],
                [
                    "eid2230",
                    "opacity",
                    90,
                    160,
                    "easeOutQuad",
                    "${Bubble_01}",
                    '0',
                    '0.49659030720339'
                ],
                [
                    "eid2231",
                    "opacity",
                    250,
                    750,
                    "easeOutQuad",
                    "${Bubble_01}",
                    '0.4965899884700775',
                    '0.5'
                ],
                [
                    "eid2232",
                    "opacity",
                    1000,
                    1000,
                    "easeOutQuad",
                    "${Bubble_01}",
                    '0.5',
                    '0'
                ],
                [
                    "eid2201",
                    "location",
                    0,
                    2000,
                    "easeOutQuad",
                    "${Bubble_01}",
                    [[22.23, 22.57, 0, 0, 0, 0,0],[37.23, -71.23, -75.36, -182.55, -64.78, -156.91,99.63],[39.24, -257.75, -17.9, -162.49, -20.57, -186.71,288.05],[-15.3, -365.28, 0, 0, 0, 0,410.23]]
                ],
                [
                    "eid2203",
                    "location",
                    500,
                    2000,
                    "easeOutQuad",
                    "${Bubble_02}",
                    [[23.29, 18.78, 0, 0, 0, 0,0],[58.43, -65.15, -99.73, -231.78, -45.91, -106.69,95.65],[57.39, -269.81, 85.4, -51.39, 102.76, -61.84,310.38],[66.53, -365.66, 0, 0, 0, 0,411.13]]
                ]
            ]
        }
    },

</pre>
```

My question is this: Is a conversion even possible between the two libraries? I've already spent a day on this and don't fancy wasting any more time trying to do something that isn't going to work.

I'm not looking for a tool to handle this conversion as this is a learning exercise (one where I think i've bitten more than I can chew), but more of an example or an explanation about how I would go about converting the GSAP timeline or even just the custom easing part to Velocity JS code.

Really appreciate any input on this.

Many thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that will simply do a direct conversion, but if there is a specific part you are struggling to animate, then maybe focus on that in the question.

Comment: possible for you to show what the output from **Edge Animate** looked like? because, may be you don't need to try and _convert_ the code into **Velocity** but rather, approach it as if you were trying to animate it from scratch? my humble opinion.

Comment: ... and if the resulting animation is something that requires _sequences of animation_ to animate one after another then I would totally recommend staying with **GSAP** as this tool does provide some really nice features out of the box.